# package clash between auto-pst-pdf and trimspaces

Tags: color, auto-pst-pdf

The code below is an MWE illustrating a clash between the `auto-pst-pdf` and `trimspaces` packages.      Code is a bit complicated because of the various things I want to do, but I've stripped all of those out.      I'm running the code with `pdflatex --shell-escape`.   The error that is thrown is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \usepackage
               {trimspaces
```

If I exclude the dvipsnames option to xcolor it runs without error.

Any advise as to how to fix the clash would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{amsart}%
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\DefineColorCommands[1]{\@define@color@commands{#1}}
\def\@define@color@commands#1{%
  \@define@color@commands@aux#1,\relax\q@stop
}
\def\@define@color@commands@aux#1,#2\q@stop{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname\trim@spaces{#1}\endcsname##1{%
      \noexpand\textcolor{\trim@spaces{#1}}{##1}%
    }%
    \ifx\relax#2\else
      \@define@color@commands@aux#2\q@stop
    \fi
  }{}%
}
\makeatother
\DefineColorCommands{
    Apricot,
    Aquamarine,
    Bittersweet
}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `auto-pst-pdf` *after* `xcolor` with option, or load`[dvipsnames]` as a document class option.

Comment: Note that adding `dvispsnames` is exactly what LaTeX suggests if you do as it states in the error message you quoted and type `h` to get more help.

Comment: Thanks Bernard and David.   My actual application was much more complex than the MWE, but I managed to re-order things so that `xcolor` is now loaded before `auto-pst-pdf`, and all is well for now.    It is, however, disturbing/frustrating that compilation success is so sensitive to package ordering